# Gnuplot legend errorbar symbol vertical

Tags: gnuplot, legend

How can I possibly make the legend error symbol vertical instead of horizontal with the gnuplot? `set key vertical` does not give the desired result:

```
set key vertical
plot "file.txt" using 1:2:3 with yerrorbars
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: set terminal post color eps
set output "test1.eps"

set key vertical

plot\
 "test.txt" using ($1):($2):($3) with yerrorbars title "test"

Comment: You can't change the orientation of the errorbars in the key, as you may also see, xerrorbars, yerrorbars and xyerrorbars give the same key samples.

Comment: Right, that's what I observed. For my plots, I wanted to show the average size of the  yerrorbars in the key  without actually plotting yerrorbars. This would be more meaningful if I could plot it vertically - y-axis scale for the average yerrorbar. Anyway, thank you for your response.

Comment: You can use `set arrow` with the correct `size` settings to plot such an error bar manually at some position

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Thank you once again.

Comment: OK, then you could answer your own question to close the issue

Comment: I've went ahead and answered this question. I attributed your comment, @Christoph.

Comment: @Justastudent Thats fine, thanks for the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Thanks to a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218955/gnuplot-legend-errorbar-symbol-vertical#comment48583306_30218955) by [Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2604213/christoph) for the idea.*</sup>

As indicated by [Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2604213/christoph) in comments on the question, there is no built-in way to change the orientation of the [errorbars](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node140.html) in the legend: [xerrorbars](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node260.html), [yerrorbars](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node262.html) and [xyerrorbars](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node261.html) all are horizontal.

[image: Horizontal error bars in Gnuplot, the default in the legend]

To get vertical error bars, one could consider disabling the legend (`unset key`) and drawing it manually using `set label` and `set arrow`. The error bars can namely be drawn as an arrow with two heads, shaped as a line perpendicular to the arrow line. This could look like:

```
# definition of arrow styles and line styles here, something like:
#   set style line 41 lc rgb "#cccccc" lt 1 lw 1 ps 0.5 pt 6
#   set style arrow 1 heads size screen 0.008,90 ls 1
#   ...

set label "class 1" at graph 0.7, graph 1                         # label
set arrow as 1  from graph 1, graph 0.97  to graph 1, graph 1.02  # arrow
set label ""    at   graph 1, graph 0.99  point ls 1              # dot

set label "class 2" at graph 0.7, graph 0.8                       # label
set arrow as 2  from graph 1, graph 0.77  to graph 1, graph 0.82  # arrow
set label ""    at   graph 1, graph 0.79  point ls 2              # dot
```

[image: Manually drawn vertical error bars]

You can of course tweak the length of the bars, their position, dot size, perpendicular lines length, ...